# Sqlite-JDBC create table syntax error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to create tables in my sqlite database using Java . but it keep getting wrong syntax error >_< on the last table ORDER, this table have 2 foreign keys.

...I'm not sure what I did wrong, can anyone check and tell me my mistake please?

Heres the code:

```
public boolean CreateTables() {
    Connection cn = getConnected();
    String createCategory = "Create table Category("
            + "id text primary key not null,"
            + "name text not null,"
            + "deliverday int not null,"
            + "isdelete bit not null"
            + ")";

    String createCustomer = "Create table Customer("
            + "id text primary key not null,"
            + "name text not null,"
            + "email text not null,"
            + "phone text not null,"
            + "address text not null,"
            + "isdelete boolean not null"
            + ")";

    String createOrder = "Create table Order("
            + "id text primary key not null,"
            + "custid text references Category(id) no null,"
            + "catid text references Customer(id) not null,"
            + "orderdate date not null,"
            + "delieverdate date not null,"
            + "description text not null,"
            + "requirement text not null,"
            + "price int not null,"
            + "image text not null,"
            + "product text not null,"
            + "state text not null,"
            + ")";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst;
        try {
            System.out.println("*** Create table Category");

            pst = cn.prepareStatement(createCategory);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();

            System.out.println("*** Category created Successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*** Failed to create Category");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("*** Create table Customer");

            pst = cn.prepareStatement(createCustomer);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();

            System.out.println("*** Customer created Successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*** Failed to create Customer");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        try {
            System.out.println("*** Create table Order");

            pst = cn.prepareStatement(createOrder);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();

            System.out.println("*** Order created successsfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*** Failed to create Order");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("*** COMPLETE CREATING TABLE PROCESS ****");


        cn.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Heres the Error.

```
*** Start to connection Sqlite
*** Connected to Sqlite successfully
*** Create table Category
*** Category created Successfully
*** Create table Customer
*** Customer created Successfully
*** Create table Order
*** Failed to create Order
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Order": syntax error)
*** COMPLETE CREATING TABLE PROCESS ****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed all my lil mistakes, its turned out like this:

Before I Fix

```
String createOrder = "Create table Order("
        + "id text primary key not null,"
        + "custid text references Category(id) no null,"
        + "catid text references Customer(id) not null,"
        + "orderdate date not null,"
        + "delieverdate date not null,"
        + "description text not null,"
        + "requirement text not null,"
        + "price int not null,"
        + "image text not null,"
        + "product text not null,"
        + "state text not null,"
        + ")";
```

After I Fix:

```
String createOrder = "Create table Orders("
    + "id text primary key not null,"
    + "custid text references Category(id),"
    + "catid text FOREIGN KEY references Customer(id),"
    + "orderdate date not null,"
    + "delieverdate date not null,"
    + "description text not null,"
    + "requirement text not null,"
    + "price int not null,"
    + "image text not null,"
    + "product text not null,"
    + "state text not null"
    + ")";
```

Comment: you forgot to fix the second column `custid`.

Answer (score 4):

Order is [sqllite reserved workd/keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). I would suggest change table name from `Order` to `Orders` or something like that and try.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo here :

```
+ "custid text references Category(id) no null,"
```

Should be

```
+ "custid text references Category(id) not null,"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using reserved keyword plus you forget to mention `foreign` keyword in your query. It should be like this :

```
String createOrder = "Create table Cus_Order("
        + "id text primary key not null,"
        + "custid text FOREIGN KEY references Category(id) not null,"
        + "catid text FOREIGN KEY references Customer(id) not null,"
        + "orderdate date not null,"
        + "delieverdate date not null,"
        + "description text not null,"
        + "requirement text not null,"
        + "price int not null,"
        + "image text not null,"
        + "product text not null,"
        + "state text not null,"
        + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your String createOrder two mistakes are there:

1.

Instead of 'not null' you have used 'no null'

```
+"custid text references Category(id) no null,"
```

Correct it as

```
+"custid text references Category(id) not null,"
```

2.

After the last field no need of comma, here you used a comma after the last field.

```
+ "state text not null,"
```

Remove the comma like

```
+ "state text not null"
```